# how can I send long content from a from to latest xampp database?

Tags: php, database, xampp, localhost

I already tried several time to insert long content to localhost database but I filled to insert.Even I tried a method (mysql_real_escape_string) in my content relating objectives to fix it that is given below.

I already Tried

```
$content =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);


<?php
require_once('function.php');


if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);

    $randomnumber = rand(1,100).rand(1,100);

    $url = "?page=".$randomnumber;

    $addhere = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO newcomer (title, content, url, pageid) VALUES('$title', '$content', '$url', '$randomnumber')");

}

?>
```

Comment: There's no particular in sending long content. Show full code - with query text and it's execution. Also, if you use `mysql` consider moving to `PDO` or `mysqli`, because `mysql` extension is deprecated and __removed__ in php since version 7.

Comment: <?php
require_once('function.php');


if(isset($_POST['add'])){

 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $content =mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);

 $randomnumber = rand(1,100).rand(1,100);

 $url = "?page=".$randomnumber;

 $addhere = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO newcomer (title, content, url, pageid) VALUES('$title', '$content', '$url', '$randomnumber')");

}

?>

Comment: `mysqli`, `mysql`. are you sure you understand difference between them?

Comment: Yep i got it ****** $content =mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['content']);*********Its works properly.....but still I am in confusion about logic on it.